# SSH Terminal like SecureCRT

Tags: ssh

On Windows I used to use SecureCRT and GNS3. Ubuntu also has GNS3 and its free.

Is there a free alternative to SecureCRT, an SSH terminal which has a multi-tab facility to access multiple routers at same time.

Comment: Most terminal applications offer tabbed interfaces. I dont know of any as unique as SecureCRT however you could accomplish the result with your window manager and tabbed terminal windows.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with [mikeymop](/questions/758516/ssh-terminal-like-securecrt#comment1133504_758516): [Gnome Terminal](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-terminal/), the default terminal emulator of Ubuntu, supports tabs (see below). So do many other popular terminal emulators. You could easily run `ssh` in any or each of the tabs.

[image: Gnome Terminal tabs]

An other options would be a terminal multiplexer like [`screen`](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screen/) or [`tmux`](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tmux/).

Comment: Thank you, he could easily use tabs, and graduate to tmux to get even closer to his desired effect.

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!